# Plotly: hovertemplate : custom_data not showing

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following dataframe

```
publicationDate signingDate  nif_contratante                                        contratante  ...                                         contratada         contract_date  price reported
0      24-02-2020  04-02-2020      600081290.0             Agrupamento de Escolas de Porto de Mós  ...               The Irish College of English Limited  2020-02-04T00:00:00Z   7914      NaN
1      26-02-2020  13-02-2020      600000052.0        Instituto de Oftalmologia do Dr. Gama Pinto  ...                 Instituto de Soldadura e Qualidade  2020-02-13T00:00:00Z     90      NaN
2      27-02-2020  27-02-2020      501442600.0  Instituto do Emprego e da Formação Profissiona...  ...  ASSOCIAÇÃO HUMANITÁRIA DOS BOMBEIROS VOLUNTÁRI...  2020-02-27T00:00:00Z    500      NaN
```

And the following code:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('basecovid19_ad.csv')

chart3=px.bar(x=data['contract_date'], y=data['price'], color= data['price'],
            range_x=['2020-03-01','2021-05-01'],
            labels=dict(x="Data de Publicação", y="Valor (M€)", color="Valor em Euros",
            custom_data=[data['contratante'], data['contratada']])
            )
            
chart3.update_xaxes(title_font=dict(size=18, family='Lato', color='#1a1a1e'))

chart3.update_yaxes(title_font=dict(size=18, family='Lato', color='#1a1a1e'))

chart3.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "DATA: %{x}",
        "VALOR: %{y}",
        "Entidade: {contratante}",
        "Empresa: {contratada}",
     ])
    )
chart3.show()
```

This is the result:
[image: Resulting Hover Label]

For some reason `custom_data` is not pulling the values from the `data` dataframe, or my script has some error that I'm not able to sort out.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has the wrong curly brackets in the label dictionary. Also, since it is express, you can specify df to specify the column name. I am fixing the custom data. Also, as you mentioned in your comment, you need % as an identifier and you need to specify it in the index of custom_data.

```
import plotly.express as px

chart3=px.bar(data, x=data['contract_date'], y=data['price'], color=data['price'],
            range_x=['2020-01-01','2021-05-01'],
            labels=dict(x="Data de Publicação", y="Valor (M€)", color="Valor em Euros"),
            custom_data=['contratante', 'contratada']
            )
            
chart3.update_xaxes(title_font=dict(size=18, family='Lato', color='#1a1a1e'))

chart3.update_yaxes(title_font=dict(size=18, family='Lato', color='#1a1a1e'))

chart3.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "DATA: %{x}",
        "VALOR: %{y}",
        "Entidade: %{customdata[0]}",
        "Empresa: %{customdata[1]}",
     ])
    )
chart3.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps just missing a `%` before `{contratante}` and `{contratada}`?